# Best ruby idiom for "nil or zero"

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, idioms, null

I am looking for a concise way to check a value to see if it is nil or zero.  Currently I am doing something like:

```
if (!val || val == 0)
  # Is nil or zero
end
```

But this seems very clumsy.

Comment: What should happen if val is equal to `false`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Objects have a [*nil?* method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-nil-3F).

```
if val.nil? || val == 0
  [do something]
end
```

Or, for just one instruction:

```
[do something] if val.nil? || val == 0
```

Comment: watch out for use of "or" and "and", btw, they have different and very low precedence compared to || and &&. See http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/08/ruby-operator-precedence-of-and-which.html for some remarks.

Comment: I agree with some poster of the "smell" in the question, however to me this is more the ruby way.

Comment: The precedence of `or` does not require any parens here, and will read completely naturally to an experienced Rubyist.  The only people who are ever bitten by `||` versus `or` are people who have never programmed Perl :)

Comment: The only time you need to worry about || versus OR precedence is in assignment, not boolean checking.  However, the low precedence of the word can be very handy for error checking.

Comment: I think `val && val == 0` is better.

Comment: It happens that `nil.to_i == 0`, hence, I'd suggest: `val.to_i.zero?`

Answer (score 44):

From Ruby 2.3.0 onward, you can combine the safe navigation operator (`&.`) with [`Numeric#nonzero?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F). `&.` returns `nil` if the instance was `nil` and `nonzero?` - if the number was `0`:

```
unless val&.nonzero?
  # Is nil or zero
end
```

Or postfix:

```
do_something unless val&.nonzero?
```

Comment: This was a terrific new and modern answer.  Also, there's a great article on why using it here: [The Safe Navigation Operator (&.) in Ruby](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/)

Comment: Very concise, but without the comment it would take me a moment to understand that `unless val&.nonzero?` translates to "if val is nil or zero"

Comment: @Stefan, agreed. I wouldn't use this in production code myself. I included it for completionism. The opposite is perfectly readable though - `do_something if val&.nonzero?` (aka if `val` is not `nil` and not zero).

Comment: Thanks for this. Still works as of ruby 2.7.7. I was able to use your solution to fix my ternary statement `my_value&.nonzero? ? do_something : do_something_else`

Answer (score 38):

If you really like method names with question marks at the end:

```
if val.nil? || val.zero?
  # do stuff
end
```

Your solution is fine, as are a few of the other solutions.

Ruby can make you search for a pretty way to do everything, if you're not careful.

Answer (score 30):

First off I think that's about the most concise way you can check for that particular condition.

Second, to me this is a code smell that indicates a potential flaw in your design.  Generally nil and zero shouldn't mean the same thing.  If possible you should try to eliminate the possibility of val being nil before you hit this code, either by checking that at the beginning of the method or some other mechanism.

You might have a perfectly legitimate reason to do this in which case I think your code is good, but I'd at least consider trying to get rid of the nil check if possible.

Comment: Very right about the code smell! +1
Might consider looking into NullObject pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Answer (score 10):

nil.to_i returns zero, so I often do this:

```
val.to_i.zero?
```

However, you will get an exception if val is ever an object that does not respond_to #to_i.

Comment: for reference: [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/480206/2799887) and what @AndrewGrimm said about it: `"5".to_i == 5, but you're more or less right. Clever but doesn't actually work`

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Object.nil? to test for nil specifically (and not get caught up between false and nil).  You can monkey-patch a method into Object as well.

```
class Object
   def nil_or_zero?
     return (self.nil? or self == 0)
   end
end

my_object = MyClass.new
my_object.nil_or_zero?
==> false
```

This is not recommended as changes to Object are difficult for coworkers to trace, and may make your code unpredictable to others.

Comment: I would modify the Numeric class rather than Object.

Comment: epochwolf, if you put this on the Numeric class, then `nil?` would always return false. `nil?` only returns true on the NilClass.

Comment: You could implement the method in `Object`, `NilClass` and `Numeric`. `Object` would return `false`, `NilClass` would return `true` and `Numeric` would return `zero?`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe your code is incorrect; it will in fact test for three values: `nil`, **`false`**, and zero. This is because the `!val` expression is true for all values that are false, which in Ruby is `nil` and `false`.

The best I can come up with right now is

```
if val == nil || val == 0
  # do stuff
end
```

Which of course is not very clever, but (very) clear.

Comment: you can probably assume that the variable in question is a Numeric.  If you don't even know whether it's a Boolean or a Numeric there are bigger problems in the code.

Answer (score 4):

My solution also use Refinements, minus the conditionals.

```
module Nothingness
  refine Numeric do
    alias_method :nothing?, :zero?
  end

  refine NilClass do
    alias_method :nothing?, :nil?
  end
end

using Nothingness

if val.nothing?
  # Do something
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Short and clear

`[0, nil].include?(val)`

Comment: Can also reverse that: `val.in? [0,nil]`

Comment: @mahemoff that is certainly the best idiom for it!

Comment: @mahemoff better use include?,since its faster than in?
ref:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272550/difference-between-in-and-include-in-rails

Comment: Good point, but I ran it just now on modern Ruby and in? was actually faster for a single invocation, and for 1000 invocations, they are quite similar. Both are blazing-fast anyway, enough that few applications would be affected imo. https://gist.github.com/mahemoff/7232648e1ccb9d23e0f4670913400bd8

Answer (score 3):

Shortest and best way should be

```
if val&.>(0)
  # do something
end
```

For `val&.>(0)`
it returns nil when val is nil since > basically is also a method, nil equal to false in ruby. It return false when `val == 0`.

Comment: Shortest over what?, best way than what?

Answer (score 2):

Rails does this via attribute query methods, where in addition to false and nil, 0 and "" also evaluate to false.

```
if (model.attribute?) # => false if attribute is 0 and model is an ActiveRecord::Base derivation
```

However it has its share of detractors. http://www.joegrossberg.com/archives/002995.html

Comment: Link doesn't work. I'm curious about the method `#attribute`, cause I can't find anything like that.

Comment: It is something that Rails/ActiveRecord adds on the fly. If Customer has a name field, name? is auto-added to check if the name is blank or nil. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html - search for section 'attribute query methods'

Answer (score 2):

To be as idiomatic as possible, I'd suggest this.

```
if val.nil? or val == 0
    # Do something
end
```

Because:

- It uses the nil? method.
- It uses the "or" operator, which is preferable to ||.
- It doesn't use parentheses, which are not necessary in this case. Parentheses should only be used when they serve some purpose, such as overriding the precedence of certain operators.

Comment: Although I know this is from literally 7 years ago, I downvoted because of this: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or

Answer (score 0):

I deal with this by defining an "is?" method, which I can then implement differently on various classes. So for Array, "is?" means "size>0"; for Fixnum it means "self != 0"; for String it means "self != ''". NilClass, of course, defines "is?" as just returning nil.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` if you like:

```
 case val with nil, 0
      # do stuff
 end
```

Then you can use anything that works with `===`, which is nice sometimes. Or do something like this:

```
not_valid = nil, 0
case val1 with *not_valid
      # do stuff
 end
 #do other stuff
 case val2 with *not_valid, false    #Test for values that is nil, 0 or false
      # do other other stuff
 end
```

It's not exactly good OOP, but it's very flexible and it works. My `if`s usually end up as `case`s anyway.

Of course `Enum.any?`/`Enum.include?` kind of works too ... if you like to get really cryptic:

```
if [0, nil].include? val
    #do stuff
end
```

The right thing to do is of course to define a method or function. Or, if you have to do the same thing with many values, use a combination of those nice iterators.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Rails `blank?` method for that kind of things, but it won't return `true` for `0`. So you can add your method:

```
def nil_zero? 
  if respond_to?(:zero?) 
    zero? 
  else 
    !self 
  end 
end
```

And it will check if some value is nil or 0:

```
nil.nil_zero?
=> true
0.nil_zero?
=> true
10.nil_zero?
=> false

if val.nil_zero?
  #...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very concise:

```
if (val || 0) == 0
  # Is nil, false, or zero.
end
```

It works as long as you don't mind treating `false` the same as `nil`. In the projects I've worked on, that distinction only matters once in a while. The rest of the time I personally prefer to skip `.nil?` and have slightly shorter code.

[**Update**: I don't write this sort of thing any more. It works but is too cryptic. I have tried to set right my misdeeds by changing the few places where I did it.]

By the way, I didn't use `.zero?` since this raises an exception if `val` is, say, a string. But `.zero?` would be fine if you know that's not the case.

Comment: `[edited]` I thought that if `val` was nil then this expression would evaluate to `nil == 0` (and thus return `false`). However it appears it does actually work, although I don't think it is very readable.

Comment: I now believe my approach here was too cryptic, just to save a few characters, and I wouldn't write it like this nowadays. So I don't expect any upvotes, but I am a little surprised at the downvotes for a working answer (although it was of dubious taste)...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of monkey patching a class, [you could use refinements](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) starting in Ruby 2.1. Refinements are similar to monkey patching; in that, they allow you to modify the class, but the modification is limited to the scope you wish to use it in.

This is overkill if you want to do this check once, but if you are repeating yourself it's a great alternative to monkey patching.

```
module NilOrZero
  refine Object do
    def nil_or_zero?
      nil? or zero?
    end
  end
end

using NilOrZero
class Car
  def initialize(speed: 100)
    puts speed.nil_or_zero?
  end
end

car = Car.new              # false
car = Car.new(speed: nil)  # true
car = Car.new(speed: 0)    # true
```

[Refinements were changed](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4409740) in the last minute to be scoped to the file. So earlier examples may have shown this, which will not work.

```
class Car
  using NilOrZero
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This evaluates to true for nil and zero: `nil.to_s.to_d == 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
unless (val || 0).zero?

    # do stufff

end
```

Answer (score 0):

In a single stretch you can do this:

```
[do_something] if val.to_i == 0
```

`nil.to_i` will return `0`

Answer (score -1):

Another solution:

```
if val.to_i == 0
  # do stuff
end
```

Comment: This only works if val is either an integer or nil; 0.5.to_i == 0, any_string.to_i == 0, etc.

Comment: `"5".to_i == 5`, but you're more or less right. Clever but doesn't actually work.

Answer (score -3):

```
val ||= 0
if val == 0
# do something here
end
```

Comment: -1: What if the value in `val` needs to be kept? You're clobbering the input data with this method, and there are better, less destructive ways to check for nil or zero.

Comment: How about

 if (val || 0).zero?