# Checking if a variable is not nil and not zero in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am using the following code to check if a variable is not nil and not zero

```
if(discount != nil && discount != 0) 
  ...
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Probably because it's an exact copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209495/best-ruby-idiom-for-nil-or-zero.

Comment: What should it do if `discount` is false?

Comment: I think `discount.in? [0, nil]` the cleaner way possible

Answer (score 495, accepted):

```
unless discount.nil? || discount == 0
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Using 'or' is dangerous.  'or' has lower operator presendence than '=', so the following has unexpected behaviour:
a = false or true #a is false after this statement

Comment: Current "Ruby Style Guide" stands `The and and or keywords are banned. It's just not worth it. Always use && and || instead.`. And it's right, for David and Tom reasons.

Comment: I took 20 minutes to realize it is `nil` (not `nul`)! This is what it's like to be a newbie at programming (for someone who's been writing code for 17 years!).

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, I'd like to point out that `unless` with multiple boolean conditions is discouraged by multiple sources (just google a bit...). It's more difficult to reason about what is happening because the logic is reversed. I'd really just keep this with the `if` clause.

Comment: RuboCop tells me that `.zero?` is to be preferred over `== 0` (same for negated)

Answer (score 42):

```
class Object
  def nil_zero?
    self.nil? || self == 0
  end
end

# which lets you do
nil.nil_zero? # returns true
0.nil_zero?   # returns true
1.nil_zero?   # returns false
"a".nil_zero? # returns false

unless discount.nil_zero?
  # do stuff...
end
```

Beware of the usual disclaimers... great power/responsibility, monkey patching leading to the dark side etc.

Comment: To my understanding, the opposite was asked, so you could also write `def real_value; self != 0 ? self : nil; end`, maybe even additionally. I couldn't come up with a better name then `real_value`. And RuboCop tells me that `.zero?` is to be preferred over `== 0` (same for negated)

Answer (score 35):

ok, after 5 years have passed....

```
if discount.try :nonzero?
  ...
end
```

It's important to note that `try` is defined in the ActiveSupport gem, so it is not available in plain ruby.

Comment: Note that this is a **rails-specific** answer. Vanilla ruby does not have a `try` method.

Comment: Correct. Although it is more like ActiveSupport-specific, which is a much lighter and widely used dependency than the full rails. Anyway now @ndn's response is the right one.

Comment: The answer now duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/34819818/1954610 ... I think there is value in leaving it as `try` to show the alternative option (this is why it was upvoted in the first place!), so long as it's clear to the reader that `ActiveSupport` is not vanilla ruby.

Answer (score 35):

From Ruby 2.3.0 onward, you can combine the safe navigation operator (`&.`) with [`Numeric#nonzero?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-nonzero-3F). `&.` returns `nil` if the instance was `nil` and `nonzero?` - if the number was `0`:

```
if discount&.nonzero?
  # ...
end
```

Or postfix:

```
do_something if discount&.nonzero?
```

Comment: **`"foo"&.nonzero? # => NoMethodError: undefined method 'nonzero?' for "foo":String`** .... This is not safe to use on arbitrary objects.

Comment: @TomLord, as stated in the previous comment, this was not intended to work with arbitrary objects. Instead it is concerned with the case when you have something you know should be a number, but might also be `nil`.

Comment: @TomLord, it is stated in the answer *"`nonzero?` - if the **number** was `0`"*. Also the need to check if a completely arbitrary object is `0` arises extremely rarely compared to that to check a number that may or may not be `nil`. Hence it is almost implied. Even if someone somehow makes the contrary assumption, they will instantly understand what is happening when they try to execute it.

Comment: I do think that @TomLord has a point and use constructs like `value.respond_to?(:nonzero) && value.nonzero?` all over my code for that exact reason.

Answer (score 29):

```
unless [nil, 0].include?(discount) 
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Beautiful? Yes.
Readable? Not really.

Comment: I find this perfectly readable, and I would prefer it over a new class. Well done.

Comment: The most rubyist approach of handling two conditions.

Answer (score 23):

You could do this:

```
if (!discount.nil? && !discount.zero?)
```

The order is important here, because if `discount` is `nil`, then it will not have a `zero?` method. Ruby's short-circuit evaluation should prevent it from trying to evaluate `discount.zero?`, however, if `discount` is `nil`.

Comment: I'm doing something like `discount.respond_to?(:nonzero) ? discount : discount.nonzero?` for robustness. This is also very rubyish as `5.nonzero? # => 5`

Answer (score 18):

```
if (discount||0) != 0
  #...
end
```

Comment: RuboCop tells me that `.zero?` is to be preferred over `== 0` (same for negated)

Answer (score 11):

You can convert your empty row to integer value and check zero?.

```
"".to_i.zero? => true
nil.to_i.zero? => true
```

Comment: careful: 0.1.to_i == 0

Comment: @oivoodoo I think `.to_f` is superior then `.to_i` in respect to the previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
if discount and discount != 0
  ..
end
```

update, it will `false` for `discount = false`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we do have a clean way in ruby.

```
discount.to_f.zero?
```

This check handles good amount of cases i.e. discount may be nil, discount may be int 0, discount may be float 0.0, discount may be string "0.0", "0".

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the `NilClass` provided `#to_i` method, which will return zero for `nil` values:

```
unless discount.to_i.zero?
  # Code here
end
```

If `discount` can be fractional numbers, you can use `#to_f` instead, to prevent the number from being rounded to zero.

Comment: **Does not work for arbitrary objects**. `"".to_i == "foo".to_i == "0".to_i == 0`. Your method will make all sorts of unintended type coercions. It will also fail with a `NoMethodError` if `discount` does not respond to `to_i`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_nil_and_zero(data)
     data.blank? || data == 0 
end
```

If we pass "" it will return false whereas blank? returns true.
Same is the case when data = false
blank? returns true for nil, false, empty, or a whitespace string.
So it's better to use blank? method to avoid empty string as well.

Comment: `blank?` is a rails-specific method, and not available in vanilla ruby.

Comment: You are correct!! I thought that this is related to "ror" tag so posted here. My mistake. This is not gonna work in vanilla ruby.

Comment: I would name this method `blank_or_zero?`

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using a more cleaner approach  :

```
val.to_i.zero?
```

`val.to_i` will return a `0` if **val** is a `nil`,

after that, all we need to do is check whether the final value is a **zero**.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a **database record**, I like to initialize all empty values with 0, using the migration helper:

```
add_column :products, :price, :integer, default: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize discount to 0 as long as your code is guaranteed not to try and use it before it is initialized.  That would remove one check I suppose, I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
if discount.nil? || discount == 0
  [do something]
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternative solution is to use Refinements, like so:

```
module Nothingness
  refine Numeric do
    alias_method :nothing?, :zero?
  end

  refine NilClass do
    alias_method :nothing?, :nil?
  end
end

using Nothingness

if discount.nothing?
  # do something
end
```

Answer (score -7):

I believe the following is good enough for ruby code.  I don't think I could write a unit test that shows any difference between this and the original.

```
if discount != 0
end
```

Comment: It'd evaluate to `true` if discount were `nil`.