# Check for value presence

Tags: ruby

I use this Ruby code when I load value.

```
request_builder = "#{gateway.camelize}RequestBuilder".constantize
```

But from time to time value gateway is missing from the yml configuration file. How I can add check is this value present? For example if value `gateway` is empty I want to print some message and stop code execution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a variable is not nil and not zero in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252203/checking-if-a-variable-is-not-nil-and-not-zero-in-ruby)

Comment: How do you fetch the `gateway` value from the configuration file?

Comment: @Stefan yes - from yam file

Comment: But how exactly? Could you show the code to set the `gateway` variable?

Answer (score 0):

You could just ask gateway:

```
unless gateway&.empty?
```

Or with ActiveSupport (Rails):

```
if gateway.present?
```

So raise an exception if gateway is not present:

```
fail "gateway not present" unless gateway.present?
request_builder = "#{gateway.camelize}RequestBuilder".constantize
```

(Btw `fail` is an alias of `raise`. Some people prefer to use `raise` only inside `rescue` blocks and `fail` otherwise, but that's just a matter of taste.)

---

Update: Removed the `&` from `&.present?` since ActiveSupport defines `present?` on `NilClass`.

Comment: No need for lonely operator with `present?`. `gateway.present?` will just work.

Comment: Not if the config file doesn't contain that key at all. However, if `gateway` is guaranteed not to be `nil`, yes, the ampersand is obsolete.

Comment: Try it with nil.

Comment: If it's guaranteed to not be nil, this entire question/answer is irrelevant :)

Comment: Not really. Say in a Rails app, you have different YAML config files per environment and not all of them hold all the keys. You might want to raise an understandable exception or handle it gracefully if `gateway` is `nil`. Whether it can be `nil` depends on how you parse the YAML and assign the value to `gateway`.

Comment: What I'm saying is, `nil.present?` won't crash. l̶o̶n̶e̶l̶y̶   safe-navigation operator is redundant there.

Comment: Ah, you're right, keep forgetting how "pragmatic" ActiveSupport is. Fixed it in my answer. Thanks @SergioTulentsev