# Dealing with expected nils

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null

I expect to see a nil returned with the following embedded Ruby:

```
<%=h [@inventory.origin.code] %>
```

*it returns a "NoMethodError nil object"*. However when an object is in fact present, it functions just fine (as expected).

Therefore I created this test (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209495/best-ruby-idiom-for-nil-or-zero) advice):

```
<b>origin_id:</b>
  <% if (@inventory.origin.code.nil? or @inventory.origin.code == 0)  %>
  <%=h [@inventory.origin] %>
  <% else %>
  <%=h @inventory.origin.code %>
  <% end %>
```

unexpectedly rails returns *NoMethodError "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!"*

Do you have any suggestions in dealing with this situation? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding the `.nil?` check too late. I am assuming it is `origin` that is nil, not `code` or you wouldn't be getting that error. Use this instead:

```
<%=h [@inventory.origin.code] unless @inventory.origin.nil? %>
```

Comment: even tidier would be using if @inventory.origin

Answer (score 1):

Refactor of dcneiner's answer:

```
<%=h [@inventory.origin.code] if @inventory.origin %>
```