# Rails: Difference between 'in?' and 'include?' in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I was going over Rails' ActiveSupport extensions and I came across the 'in?' method. To me, it looks and works exactly like the 'include?' method, but just in reverse.

```
([1..5]).include? 1
1.in? ([1..5])
```

I've been using the 'include?' method since I first started using Rails, so it's intriguing that there's another method that does exactly the same thing. Is there's some difference in the two methods that I'm missing?

**EDIT**

Is there any scenario where using 'in?' would benefit more than using 'include?' ? Because right now, all I can think is that 'in?' is a rather pointless method given 'include?' already exists for its purpose.

Comment: `include?` is an ruby array method whereas ` in? ` is a rails `activesupport` method

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in? method is available after Rails 3.1 .  So if you want to use in? method, we need to mark require 'active_support' then we can make use of in? method.

But the include? method in available for all Enumerables. Like in your normal ruby console you can try:

```
From irb: 
(1..5).include? 1 #you are checking for include? on a range.
=> true
(1..5).to_a.include? 1 # you are checking on an Array.
=> true 
2.1.5 :023 > 1.in?(1..5)
NoMethodError: undefined method `in?' for 1:Fixnum
```

From rails console:

```
1.in?(1..5)
=> true 
(1..5).include? 1
=> true
```

Check their performance:

```
 require 'benchmark'
=> false
 puts Benchmark.measure { 90000.in?(1..99000)}
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (0.000014)
 puts Benchmark.measure { (1..99000).include? 90000 }
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 ( 0.000007)
```

You can see, include? is faster than in?

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I was wondering if one more thing can be clarified. Is there any scenario where using 'in?' would benefit more than using 'include?' ? Because right now, all I can think is that 'in?' is a rather pointless method given 'include?' already exists for its purpose.

Comment: @adnann  include? is a better alternative than in?

Comment: @adnann just check my answer, I updated it with the performance comparison of those two methods.  hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks! your answer was solid. so the in? method is pointless after all.

Comment: very useful insight.

Comment: IMO the cost in performance is far outweighed by the enhanced readability. I mean c'mon, `something.in?(list)` just reads so much like a real English sentence.

Comment: `in?` makes use of `include?` anyway. So its performance will never be better than `include?`, but it contributes to better readability for sure.

Answer (score 0):

`include?` is a ruby method. `in?` is added by ActiveSupport v3.1.0 as an alternative way of doing the same thing, **for the benefit of code style / readability.**

Clearly it will run a tiny bit slower because in the source code we can see the `in?` method just calls `include?` :

```rb
def in?(another_object)
  another_object.include?(self)
rescue NoMethodError
  raise ArgumentError.new("The parameter passed to #in? must respond to #include?")
end
```

### Code style / readability?

I have to say personally I'm still very much in the habit of writing `.include?` everywhere but I've noticed this can **feel back-to-front** sometimes. For example if you're checking whether an expression evaluates to one of several values

```rb
if [1,2].include? my.big.complicated.expression
```

...is how it always had to be done before, but I think it's nicer to say...

```rb
if my.big.complicated.expression.in? [1,2]
```

So you're reading and thinking about the big complicated expression first, and then thinking about the values to compare it to at the end

Having said all that, I don't think it's *always* more readable. For example maybe you have a nice little variable x, but you've got some complicated logic to produce the array to search within:

```rb
if my.big.complicated.array_builder.include? x
```

...is perhaps better than...

```rb
if x.in? my.big.complicated.array_builder
```

I suppose I'm saying it reads better with the "heavier" part of the comparison coming first.